# php - Differences between copy, rename and move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, move, file-rename

Are there differences when I use that functions? Why should I use one instead of the other one...

Comment: How is the difference between `copy` and `rename` not immediately obvious?

Answer (score 45):

- `copy()` copies the file - you now have 2 files, and for large files, this can take very long
- `rename()` changes the file's name, which can mean moving it between directories.
- `move_uploaded_file()` is basically the same as `rename()`, but it will only work on files that have been uploaded via PHP's upload mechanism. This is a security feature that prevents users from tricking your script into showing them security-relevant data.

In the future, I suggest looking up such information in the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) yourself.

Answer (score 10):

I found this in the manual of [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php):

> **Florian S. in H. an der E. [.de]** at 17-Aug-2008 09:02
>
> move_uploaded_file (on my setup) always makes files `0600` (`rw- --- ---`) and owned by the user running the webserver (owner AND group).
>   Even though the directory has a sticky bit set to the group permissions!
>   I couldn't find any settings to change this via php.ini or even using `umask()`.
>
> I want my regular user on the server to be able to `tar cjf` the directory .. which would fail on files totally owned by the webserver-process-user;
>   the `copy(from, to)` function obeys the sticky-bit though!

so it seems like `copy` and `rename` do a slightly different work.