# Referencing file immediately after upload via $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I have a method that successfully uploads local files to an S3 bucket using the amazon SDK, all I need is a valid local `path/to/file`, which is the second param below:

```
$this->saveToAmazon($pathOnS3,$filename);
```

These local files are uploaded by the user and handled using the `$_FILES` global. Once the user uploads, we are copying to a local `uploads` folder via `move_uploaded_file()`. From there, we are calling the above function. This works fine, although this got me thinking.

Since for the life of the request, the file can be accessed temporarily via `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`, is it possible to 'hack' together a temporary valid file path to provide the `saveToAmazon()` function **without** having to call `move_uploaded_file()` and using the local uploads folder? essentially tapping in to the local `php/tmp` directly?

Comment: You _should_ be fine skipping `move_uploaded_file` these days. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276835/php-move-uploaded-file-why-is-it-important

Comment: @miken32 thanks for the reply, I saw that link - saying I 'should be fine' is not very helpful. What is the solution you're proposing instead of using `move_file_upload`? I appreciate any suggestions - p.s. `rename()` didn't work for me, the tmp file and renamed file are oth gone following the `rename()` function call.

Comment: What's wrong with `$this->saveToAmazon($pathOnS3,$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);`?

Comment: Tried it, simply doesn't work, the temp file isn't a valid / readable file  --- try this: upload a picture and try to construct a valid path using `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` or even just try to call `file_get_contents` on it - doesn't work.