# Upload File to directory on server - PHP 5.6 - file is not copied right now

Tags: php, file-upload

My upload file script was working with PHP 5.3. After upgrading to 5.6, no files copied from local to server.

I have a form which allows a user to submit a file for upload - POST. The name of the element is ufile.

My PHP script reads:

```
 $file_name = $HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'];
 //extension
 $exx = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


 $random_digit=rand(0000,9999);  //generating a unique number 
 $koubiac= strtotime("now");   //current time
 $dirPath = '../';   //directorypath

 $new_file_name=$random_digit.".".$exx;   //filename is now a random number


$uploaddirectory = $dirPath.$random_digit.$koubiac;  //upload directory is the path slash random digit concatenated with current time

mkdir($random_digit, 0755, true);  //making directory

$path= $random_digit.'/'.$new_file_name;  //path of file to save in MySQL DB table and for copying of file.

 copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'], $path);  //copy to path
```

The directory is created.
The file is not uploaded.

Any idea? Is there something different I should be doing in 5.6?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried `$_FILES` instead of `$_HTTP_POST_FILES` which is deprecated?

Comment: Also, uploads should be handled with `move_uploaded_file()`, not `copy()`

Comment: I've switched to $_Files and it works. What is the difference between move_uploaded_file and copy? Thank you.

Comment: well, when u get good advice, least you could do is [rtfm](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_HTTP_POST_FILES` is deprecated.

Use `$_FILES` instead.

Also, uploads should be handled by [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) not `copy()`

For a comparison on `copy`/`rename`/`move_uploaded_file`, see this answer:
[php - Differences between copy, rename and move_uploaded_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924016/php-differences-between-copy-rename-and-move-uploaded-file)

**tl;dr** `move_uploaded_file()` is safer