# PHP move_uploaded_file() returning FALSE

Tags: php

I've been struggling with this for more than 8h now, so I hope someone can help me. I think I went through all the posts regarding this issue, but wasn't able to find a solution.

There are no errors, both `/tmp` and `/var/www/test` are owned by apache (`www-data`) and have 775 permission set.

This is the PHP code:

```
$target_dir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "test/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["pic"]["name"]);
$uploadOK = 1;
$image_file_type = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if($uploadOK === 0) {
    echo "Upload failed!";
} else {
    // This is where it stops...
    // There is definitely something wrong with $target_file
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "Not uploaded...<br>";
        echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], $target_file) . "<br>";
        echo $target_file . "<br>";
        print_r($_FILES) . "<br>";
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    }
}
```

These are the results I get:

Not uploaded...

/var/www/test/uploads/test.jpg

```
Array (
    [pic] => Array (
        [name] => test.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpKlzCxc
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 721090
    )
)
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

**Ok, here are the updates:**

- The checking of the upload was done at the beginning of the script and it worked which is why I didn't include it in the question.
- This is the code from www.w3schools.com, and I will be checking out the other source (thanks for pointing that out)
- After fixing the position of the `error_reporting` (good call :)), finally got a whole bunch of "Permission denied" warnings as I suspected would be the problem, and here they are:

**Warning:** move_uploaded_file(/var/www/test/uploads/test.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/test/upload.php on line 47

**Warning:** move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpHzvhOA' to '/var/www/test/uploads/test.jpg' in /var/www/test/upload.php on line 47

Line 47:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
```

Permission set for /var/www/test/upload.php:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 2174 Sep  9 00:07 /var/www/test/upload.php
```

Comment: is full error checking and display on?

Comment: What does your `form` look like? Has `enctyp`?

Comment: A file probably already exists with the same name. One of various reasons you shouldn't use user provided file names.

Comment: you dont actually check the file uploaded at all

Comment: I can tell that you are using w3schools.com's tutorial on file uploads. I suggest you don't, because I myself had spent hours trying to figure out what the heck was wrong with it. w3schools.com isn't bad, just that one tutorial is a little messed up. I suggest that try this tutorial for http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/1.html beginning.

Then maybe once you have a better understanding try w3schools.com tutorial again. (accedentially made it an answer, fixed now.)

Comment: Why are you calling `move_uploaded_file()` again in the `else` block? It doesn't return anything that's useful to echo.

Comment: Put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the **beginning** of the script. You have to enable error reporting **before** the errors happen, it won't report errors that already happened.

Comment: Ok. Good point with `error_reporting`, it is at the beginning of the script now and got a whole bunch of 'Permission denied' warnings.  I will edit my post now with the warnings and the permissions that are set for those directories.  Thank you all for your support!

Comment: what about the permission for the uploads folder?? Have you already set permission for that too..

Answer (score 0):

- I would first check if `file_exists($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"])`.
- Then check if the path `$target_file` is valid (just print_r() and check the path is right).
- Make sure you have the rights to write on `$target_file` path.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer

Comment: `file_exists` returns true, so that's good. As for the other two suggestions, as mentioned above $target_file is /var/www/test/uploads/test.jpg, and I have set the permission to 775 for /tmp and /var/www/test. The /uploads folder is in the /test folder

Comment: why not then use **rename($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);**

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` is essentially the same as `rename`, but it checks that the argument is really an uploaded file for extra safety. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924016/php-differences-between-copy-rename-and-move-uploaded-file

Comment: @Jorge - Tried with `rename()` as well, unfortunately same result

Answer (score 0):

The problem was definitely with permissions as we thought. So, I ran the

`sudo chown -R www-data.www-data` and `sudo chmod -R 775` for all three directories as I did 20x before already. Only now, for some reason it worked.

I used the `-R` method which, if I understood correctly, should have changed permissions to all subfolders and files in `/var/www/test` directory, where the `/uploads` folder is located as well...

So just for clarification, if someone also has issues with this, in order to grant permission to apache, this is what I did:

1. `sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/test`
2. `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/test`

did this also for `/tmp` and `/var/www/test/uploads` directories.